# While copying an AMI image (from one region to another) in AWS create's an error that "The storage for the ami is not available in the source region"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

In AWS I create an AMI image and copy that particular image from one region to another region but it generates an error that "Failed to copy AMI - The storage for the ami is not available in the source region"

last time when I do the same Job of copying AMI and create a new EC2 instance from that copied image. I need your help to diagnose this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Machine Image (AMI) are region specific, but under certain condition can be shared, see link for details, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html

Region – AMIs are a Regional resource. When you share an AMI, it is only available in that Region. To make an AMI available in a different Region, copy the AMI to the Region and then share it. For more information, see Copy an AMI.

Answer (score 0):

When copying an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) from one region to another, if you have checked the "Encrypt EBS snapshots of AMI copy" it will fail if you use a default key.

You must create a "Customer managed key" in the Key Management Service (KMS) of the source region.  When creating the key, expand the "Advanced options" and select "Multi-Region key" in the "Regionality" section.

Once you have created the key, it will take a few minutes to copy the key to the "destination region".  Verify that the new key has a status of "Enabled" in the destination region before attempting to copy the AMI.

When you attempt to copy the AMI, and you select "Encrypt EBS snapshots of AMI copy", select your "customer managed key" you created from the drop down menu.